# Anaconda3 infinite solving environment problem

Tags: python, anaconda

I have downloaded the anaconda3 a complete newer version from official site.. I tried to create an environment but the 'solving environment' keeps on running..

[image: Screenshot of my problem]

I tried turning off windows defender but it didn't work.. someone plz help.. I am using windows 11 pro, and I have downloaded and installed Anaconda3-2022.10-Windows-x86_64 on 23/12/2022

Answer (score 0):

The actively available Anaconda builds for Python 3.6 all use 3.6.10, so you would have a possibly easier solve with:

```bash
conda create -n ssd_env python=3.6 anaconda
```

However, there is the `custom` build, `anaconda=custom=py36_1` that should be generally compatible with `python>=3.6,<3.7`. That is what I get when simulating the solve from OP:

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=win-64 mamba create -n ssd_env --override-channels -c anaconda python=3.6.8 anaconda
```

which solves almost instantly with Mamba.

Using `conda` also takes unreasonably long for me, even when explicitly identifying the `anaconda=custom=py36_1`. The reason this takes so long is that this `anaconda` package has no version constraints on the 100+ packages it specifies, which means a *huge* search space. This is aggravated by the fact that the solvers work from latest to oldest package versions, and the versions that are expected to be identified are ~3 years down the stack.

I recommend:

1. Use Mamba as the solver.
2. Don't use the `anaconda` package unless absolutely needed. Most users do not ever need all those packages - instead just specify the packages actually required.

Comment: i used this command  -> conda create -n ssd-env python=3.6.8
instead of conda create -n ssd-env python=3.6.8 anaconda
and it worked